# Why does the nil value or empty array returned from a capybara query have a text property?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, capybara, automated-tests

Crazy question. I'm testing an angularjs app using capybara, webdriver, and firefox. I have a method that return the result of a scoped query:

```
def all_list_items
  page.within(list_container) { page.all(list_item) }
end
```

And a second method to retrieve the text property of the first result.

```
def first_result_text
  all_list_items.first.text
end
```

Sometimes this returns an empty array, ie. it didn't find anything.
When this happens I call .text on the empty array and it gives me all of the visible text on the screen.

When I call .text on the first item of the empty array (so calling it on nil) it return all of the visible text on the screen.

I'm very confused.

Comment: can you tell me what you actually want to find ? only single value or collection?

Comment: the all query should always return a collection. I'm searching for an item within a collection but the issue is more that an empty array has text.

Answer (score 0):

#all returns a Capybara::Result which doesn't have a #text method - so what class is the "empty array" you're seeing?